# Skip a record after a duplicate error (except IntegrityError)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have records that am processing and part of the process is getting rid of duplicates. With that, I've created UniqueContraints on my tables using SQLAlchemy and I have the following catch except in my save function which runs in a for loop:

**code1**

```
for record in millionsofrecords:
    try:
        #code to save 
        session.flush()
    except IntegrityError:
        logger("live_loader", LOGLEVEL.warning, "Duplicate Entry")
    except:
        logger("live_loader", LOGLEVEL.critical, "\n%s" %(sys.exc_info()[1]))
        raise
```

With the above, I capture the error okay but then SQLAlchemy states in the next loop that: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback().`. So I change to the following:

**code2**

```
for record in millionsofrecords:
    try:
        #code to save 
        session.flush()
    except IntegrityError:
        logger("live_loader", LOGLEVEL.warning, "Duplicate Entry")
        session.rollback()
    except:
        logger("live_loader", LOGLEVEL.critical, ":%s" %(sys.exc_info()[1]))
        raise
```

I change the function to include the session.rollback but then any record inserted pior to the duplicate detection is discarded.

`questions:`

1. When a duplicate is detected, I want to skip that "1" record but insert the rest that are not duplicates. When I add the `session.rollback` as shown in `code2` above, all the records that had even been flushed earlier are "discarded". I only want to discard the duplicate record but allow all the rest to be saved.
2. Which is a better design given that I'll be processing many records. Do a quick Select Statement on the DB to detect the duplication or do what am doing now and make the database Unique Keys work for me while I capture the duplication exception and move on?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing (especially if you have many records) is executing many queries and that is highly inefficient. Thus, it would be a better idea to build a query to detect duplicates. For the future you should still keep the unique constraint to avoid further conflicts, but for the transition (or whatever your are doing there) it is far more efficient to have such a query. You could even transform the results into a dictionary, because that is often more efficient if you need to look up stuff by a key.

Furthermore, concerning speed, use a `set` instead of a `list` if you need to do something like `value in duplicates` because it is more efficient.

Now if you'd like to keep your old way, use [savepoints](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#using-savepoint). The idea here is that you say "okay so far I am fine, let's keep this so when I roll back then only the last bit where I wasn't sure yet". Your example is a bit to short to give you an example, but usually, before adding stuff to the database you make a `begin_nested` and then either commit or roll back.